# Javascript: how to show a google map with marker after Ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

In my HTML page I have:

```
<div id="map" class="div5" style="float: right; display:none;">
  <p id="demo_posizione"></p>
</div>
```

and when a user performs a mouse over, this is the ajax which is triggered:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$(document).on("mouseenter", "li", function() {
    var selector = "#" + this.id; /* id della riga <li> su cui metto il mouse */
    /* se nella riga su cui si mette il mouse è indicato un venditore (ossia esiste la sottostringa "Km") */
    if($(selector).text().indexOf("Km") > -1) {
        var strings = $(selector).text().split("-");
        $("#demo_posizione").text("Posizione venditore "+strings[strings.length - 1]);
        $.ajax({
                url: "http://lainz.softwebsrl.it/ajax/venditore",
                dataType: "json",
                crossDomain: true,
                type : 'post',
                data:
                {
                    valore: vendors_ids[$(selector).index()]
                },
                success: function (data)
                {
                    showMarker(data);
                }
         });
       }
   });
});
```

and this is the function to show marker:

```
function showMarker(data) {
//1 - getting lat and long of vendor
var vendorLatLng = null;
var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

geocoder.geocode( { 'address':data['indirizzo']+" "+data['civico']+", "+data['cap']+" "+data['citta']+" "+data['provincia']+", Italia"  }, function(results, status) 
{
    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
        vendorLatLng = {lat: results[0].geometry.location.lat(), lng: results[0].geometry.location.lng()};
    } 
});

//build new google maps marker with google maps api
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 4,
    center: vendorLatLng
});

var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: vendorLatLng,
    map: map,
    title: data['venditore']
});

$(".div5").show();
console.log("si vede il marcher?");
}
```

obviously nothing is showed inside the div with id map, neither the title in `<p>`element. I have checked with `console.log()` that `data` contains all the information about the place from MySQL and they are correct. Maybe, are `google.maps.Marker()`and `google.maps.Map()` asynchronous? which is the correct way to proceed? Thank you

Comment: The geocoder is asynchronous, you need to use the returned data in the  callback function when/where it is available.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The geocoder is asynchronous, you need to use the returned data in the callback function when/where it is available.

```
function showMarker(data) {
  //1 - getting lat and long of vendor
  var vendorLatLng = null;
  var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

  geocoder.geocode( { 'address':data['indirizzo']+" "+data['civico']+", "+data['cap']+" "+data['citta']+" "+data['provincia']+", Italia"  }, function(results, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
      // not required, results[0].geometry.location is a google.maps.LatLng
      vendorLatLng = {lat: results[0].geometry.location.lat(), lng: results[0].geometry.location.lng()};
      //build new google maps marker with google maps api
      var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        zoom: 4,
        center: results[0].geometry.location
      });

      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: results[0].geometry.location,
        map: map,
        title: data['venditore']
      });
    } else alert("Geocode failed, status: "+status); 
  });
  $(".div5").show();
}
```

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/zkpypwk4/3/)

**code snippet:**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#btn").click(function() {
    showMarker({
      venditore: "Marker",
      indirizzo: "New York, NY",
      civico: "",
      cap: "",
      citta: "New York",
      provinca: "NY",
    });
  });
});

function showMarker(data) {
  //1 - getting lat and long of vendor
  var vendorLatLng = null;
  var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

  geocoder.geocode({
    'address': data['indirizzo'] + " " + data['civico'] + ", " + data['cap'] + " " + data['citta'] + " " + data['provincia'] + ", Italia"
  }, function(results, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
      // not required, results[0].geometry.location is a google.maps.LatLng
      vendorLatLng = {
        lat: results[0].geometry.location.lat(),
        lng: results[0].geometry.location.lng()
      };
      //build new google maps marker with google maps api
      var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        zoom: 4,
        center: results[0].geometry.location
      });

      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: results[0].geometry.location,
        map: map,
        title: data['venditore']
      });
    } else alert("Geocode failed, status: "+status);
  });
  $(".div5").show();
}
```

```css
html,
body,
#map {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<div id="map" class="div5" style="float: right; display:none;">
  <p id="demo_posizione"></p>
</div>
<input id="btn" type="button" value="click to show map" />
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I have just added your code but still nothing appears...maybe is the div too small?

Comment: The example in the answer works for me (I removed the ajax call as I don't a way to simulate that, but if the data returned is correct as you say, the code should work)

Comment: Is the geocoder returning status "OK"?  Just added error checking to the posted code.  Your code was written to silently fail when the geocoder didn't return results.